# Replace ownCloud with NextCloud snap package

Tags: apt, owncloud-server, nextcloud

I know that I can replace ownCloud with NextCloud by (basically) deleting some directories in the ownCloud installation directory, and replacing them with NextCloud ones. But I'm worried about auto-updating. I don't want to have to keep getting the latest NextCloud archive and unzipping it. I want the package manager to update it. I saw that NextCloud has a snap package, and I was wondering if I could migrate to NextCloud using that, so that I could retain auto-updating. I have my data on a completely separate drive.

Has anyone out there done this, or think it will work relatively easily?